# CSS GRID elements positioning horizontally is working, vertically not

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make a Navbar, but i am not able to position my text e.g "1" in the vertical middle of the header container, neither with the parent element ".header ul", nor with the child ".header ul li"

```
<div class="grid">
      <div class="header">
        <ul>
                 <li><a href="/1.html">1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/2.html">2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/3.html">3</a></li>
               </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
grid {
      width:100vw;
      height:100vh;
      display:grid;
}

header ul {
         display:grid;
         font-size: 25px;
         list-style-type: none;
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         grid-auto-flow: column;
         justify-content:space-around;
```

Comment: header is a tag not a class, idem, grid is not a class selector, .grid is  , which ones did you try to style ?

Comment: after fixing the typos, as you have set `grid-auto-flow: column` they are placed horizontally...